# Understanding the basics of the for loop in C language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char

can anyone explain the working of the for loop in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 char i=0;
 for(i<=5&&i>=-1;++i;i>0)
 printf("%d\n",i);
 getch();
  }
```

Comment: `for(a;b;c;){d;}` is the same as  `a;while(b){d;c;}`. That piece of code completely misuses the for loop. You probably want something like `for(i=0;i<=5;i++){...}` to iterate from 0 to 5.

Comment: i know this but how is the above code working?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break the for statement down, we have three phases, the initialiser, the test, and the modifier:

```
for(<Initialiser>; <Test>; <Modifier>)
    <content>;
```

In your case:

```
for(i<=5&&i>=-1;++i;i>0)
// initialiser: i<=5&&i>=-1;
// test: ++i;
// modifier: i>0
```

The initialiser is done first. Here no assignment is done. Two boolean expressions (denoted by the `>=` and `<=` operators are compared in a logical `&&`. The whole initialiser returns a boolean value but it doesn't do anything. It could be left as a blank `;` and there would be no change.

The test uses the pre-increment operator and so returns the result of `i+1`. If this result is ever `0` it evaluates as `false` and the loop will terminate. For any non-zero value it evaluates to `true` and continues. This is often used when `i` is initialised to a value less than zero and so the test will increment `i` until `i+1` results in a zero, at which point the loop terminates.

Finally we have the modifier, which in this case simply uses the `>` operator to evaluate to a boolean value. No assignment is done here either.

The fact is that you've gotten the test and the modifier confused and put them in the wrong positions but before we sort that out let's see how it would work…

We begin with:

```
char i = 0;
```

…and for all intents and purposes this does the same thing as our for loops initialiser would do in normal circumstances. The next thing to be evaluated is the for loop's initialiser:

```
i<=5 && i>=-1;
```

Because `i` is `0` it is less-than-or-equal-to `5` and it is greater-than-or-equal-to `-1`. This expression evaluates to `1` but nothing is done with that value. All we've done is waste a bit of time with an evaluation.

Next up is the modifier to test whether or not the for loop's inner block should be executed:

```
++i;
```

This evaluates to `1` and also assigns that value to `i`. Now, as it's evaluated to a non-zero number, the loop executes:

```
printf("%d\n",i);
```

And the digit `1` is printed to the screen... Now it's the modifier that gets executed:

```
i>0
```

Well, `i` is `1` so that is greater-than `0`. This evaluates to `1` (or true). Either way, this is ignored. The purpose of the modifier isn't to test or check anything. It's there so that you can change the state of the program each time the for loop iterates. Either way, the loop repeats and it will do this for a very long time. Why? Because `++i` is going to evaluate to a non-zero number for a while. Whether or not it will ever terminate depends on how your system deals with integer overflows.

This is what you meant to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   for(char i=0; i<=5&&i>=-1; ++i)
       printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Do you see the difference? Our initialiser now starts the loop with the state of `i` as zero. We then test if it's within the bounds of `-1` to `5` and each time we iterate we increment `i` by `1`. This loop will output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Why are you considering `getch();` as part of the loop?

Comment: Because I'm misreading the code! Well spotted, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: +1 for a Good explanation. One thing- put the `getch` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet:

```
 for(i<=5&&i>=-1;++i;i>0)
     printf("%d\n",i);
```

Does the same as this:

```
i<=5 && i>=-1; //statement with no effect
while(++i)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i>0; //statement with no effect
}
```

So, it's going to print `i` until `++i` evaluates to 0. This will happen after `i` overflows and becomes negative, then incrementing towards 0. That will take 255 iterations to happen, since `char`s can store up to 256 different values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( variable initialization; condition; variable update ) {
}
```

the variable initialization phase is done only once when the for loop starts.

the condition is checked everytime before running code inside the loop. if the condition is false then the loop is exited.

the variable update is done after the first iteration, from the second iteration it is done before the condition check.